# Floating First List Item to the Left and remaining list items to the right (using flexbox)

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, display

I have been trying my best to troubleshoot my header on a personal webpage. Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have a simple paragraph with "ZH" to the left. Then I have three more list-items directly to the right of the logo. What I want to do is have the three list-items float to the right, kind of like this:

[image]

Here is the current generated HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">
            <p>ZH</p>
        </a>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/about/" role="button">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/projects/" role="button">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" target="_blank" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zachary_hughes_wordpress/assets/hughes_zachary_cv.pdf" role="button">Resume</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the current CSS for the ul.nav:

```
.nav {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

Is there anyway to do this without having to change the html markup? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `justify-content: space-between` on the `.nav` if you wrap `li`'s to create two *flex-items*, which are then placed as far from each other as they can be:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* horizontal alignment / places first flex-item (child) far left and last far right, i.e. max. space between them */
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container > li {
  margin: 0 5px; /* adjust */
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">
    <p>ZH</p>
  </a>
  <ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/about/" role="button">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/projects/" role="button">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" target="_blank" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zachary_hughes_wordpress/assets/hughes_zachary_cv.pdf" role="button">Resume</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*I've used the `ul` element to wrap `li`'s and a div for the outer flex-container.*

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done **with native Bootstrap classes alone WITHOUT any custom css**. That's the beauty of Bootstrap 4.

All you need in this particular case is to add the `ml-auto` class to the `ul`. That's it!

However, there are also issues with other parts of your code. Not using the structure and the elements provided by Bootstrap 4 forces you to use custom css. And that makes using Bootstrap pretty pointless in my view. The beauty of Bootstrap 4 is that you can do almost anything without ever touching css!

I have rewritten your code to provide a clean and elegant solution that uses Bootstrap 4 classes alone and NO custom css. For example, the class `m-0` removes the unwanted margin on your brand. And if you do want a margin there, simply change 0 to 1 or 2. For horizontal only margins use `mx-1` for vertical margins `my-1` etc.

Here's the elegant code I promised:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">
           <p class="m-0">ZH</p>
       </a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/about/" role="button">About</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/projects/" role="button">Projects</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="btn btn-lg nav-link" target="_blank" href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zachary_hughes_wordpress/assets/hughes_zachary_cv.pdf" role="button">Resume</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Here's a much more elegant solution than the ones you accepted. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

This is simple example with `flex` and `justify-content` refer this site [flexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My Favorite Films</title>
 <style>
  #header{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
      background-color: pink;
  }
    
  h1{
   width: 125px;
   display: flex;
   background-color: antiquewhite;
  } 
 </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1 class="home-page-header">My Favorite Films</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added a new CSS style using your tips and I still cannot get it to work. li.nav-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

Comment: If I have multiple items inside a flex container, how do you justify-content: flex-start; and then justify-content: flex-end for the different items of the flex container?? An example with multiple items inside the header would be very helpful.

Comment: `about, project resume` are child and you should have to set `flex and justify-content ` property to its uppermost parent.

Comment: here `nav` is your child and you should add justify-content to its parent